# Validation and training accuracy high in the first epoch [Keras]

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am training an image classifier with 2 classes and 53k images, and validating it with 1.3k images using keras. Here is the structure of the neural network :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Training accuracy increases from ~50% to ~85% in the first epoch, with 85% validation accuracy. Subsequent epochs increase the training accuracy consistently, however, validation accuracy stays in the 80-90% region.

I'm curious, is it possible to get high validation and training accuracy in the first epoch? If my understanding is correct, it starts small and increases steadily with each passing epoch.

Thanks

EDIT : The image size is 150x150 after rescaling and the mini-batch size is 16.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is entirely possible to get high accuracy on first epoch and then only modest improvements.

If there is enough redundancy in the data and you make enough updates (wrt. the complexity of your model, which seems fairly easy to optimize) in the first epoch (i.e. you use small minibatches), it's entirely possible that you learn most of the important stuff during the first epoch. When you show the data again, the model will start overfitting to pecularities introduced by the specific images in your train set (thus you get increasing training accuracy), but since you do not provide any novel samples, it will not learn  anything new about the underlying properties of your classes.

You can think of your training data as an infinite stream (which actually SGD would like to enjoy all the convergence theorems). Do you think that you need more than 50k samples to learn what is important? You can actually test the data-hunger of your model by providing less data or reporting performance after a some sub-epoch number of updates.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect to get an accuracy over 90-95% with image classification using feed forward neural networks.

You need to use another architecture called Convolution Neural network, state of the art in image recognition.

Also it is very easy to build that using keras, but it is computationally more intensive than this.

If you want to stick with feed forward layers the best thing you can do is early stopping, but even that wouldn't give you accuracy over 90%.

Comment: Without knowing the nature of the data, it's ridiculous to make claims like "cannot get accuracy over 90 %". E.g. on MNIST, which is bigger data (28x28, while OP has 16*16) and has more classes (10, OP has 2) with comparable number of training examples, 2 layers are enough to achieve around 96 % test accuracy.

Comment: Sorry, we do not know the image size of  the OP. But I still believe in the rest of the argument. I think e.g. that classifying sunny day / rainy day picture should be easy enough.

Comment: The images are 150x150 in size. I'll update the question. The reason I'm not using a CNN is the lack of a GPU.

Comment: Are those rgb images of b/w

Comment: Then you must use a conv net. Your input tensor must have a dimension of (3×150×150), fairly big for standard neural networks to deal with.

Comment: Also if you don't have a GPU, you could use ML engine by Google cloud or if you want GPU for free. Try colab.research.google.com

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, epoch are supposed to fit the data on the model.

Try using 2 neurons at the end and one hot encode on ur Class label!
Like I have seen one case where I got better results doing that, instead of binary output.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!